# DataStoreで同じKind内のEntityに一意な値をつけたい

Tags: google-app-engine

DataStoreを使っているのですが、同じKind内のEntityにユニークな値を持たせたいと考えています。ただし対象のEntityには親のEntityがそれぞれあるものとします。

具体的に例をあげて説明させていただきます。
例えばユーザとユーザの所持アイテムがあったとします。
そして所持アイテムの親はユーザです。
またこのアイテムは他のユーザに移譲できるものとします。

またそれぞれのアイテムは変化しないユニークな値を割りふりたいです。
なぜならそのアイテムに紐付いているデータがあると想定されるためです。
例えば移譲回数に限度があるや、アイテムの移動ログなどです。

私の認識ではアイテムの移譲を実現するためには、一度アイテムエンティティを消して、移譲先のユーザのエンティティにアイテムを作成することで実現できると考えています。

しかしこの方法だともしDataStoreにIDを自動で振らせていた場合、キーのIDが変更されてしまいます。
しかしIDをこちらで指定してコピーすることはできません。
なぜならエンティティグループが違うため、衝突する可能性があるためです。

RDBではAutoIncrementがテーブルごとにできるため、この様な問題は起こらないのですが、DataStoreではどの様にすればこの問題が解決できるかわかりません。

ご回答頂けると助かります。

Comment: 個人的にはこういったエンティティグループを使うのはあまり賛成できませんがそれは一旦おいといて・・

`しかしIDをこちらで指定してコピーすることはできません。
なぜならエンティティグループが違うため、衝突する可能性があるためです。`

ID指定してコピーは可能なはず・・・
衝突とはどういう意味でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

アイテムのユニークな所有権の実現には、普通ならRDBの外部キーを使用すべきです。GAEに外部キーを取り扱いには、[ReferenceProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ReferenceProperty)を利用すべきです。

例えば

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Item(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

    # 所有者
    owner = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='all_items')

    # 移譲回数
    transfer_count = db.IntegerProperty()

user_a = db.Query(User).filter('name =', 'Akira').first()
user_b = db.Query(User).filter('name =', 'Benimaru').first()

# user_a のアイテムを取得
item_of_user_a = user_a.all_items.get()
if item_of_user_a is not None:
    # 所有権の変更には、ほかのユーザーオブジェクトとして設定すれば良い
    item_of_user_a.owner = user_b
    # 移譲回数を1増やす
    item_of_user_a.transfer_count += 1
    item_of_user_a.put()
```

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。「アイテムのユニークな所有権の実現には、普通ならRDBの外部キーを使用すべきです」というのはつまりこういった

Comment: 上の件、切れて５分経ってしましました。ご返信ありがとうございます。確認なのですが「アイテムのユニークな所有権の実現には、普通ならRDBの外部キーを使用すべきです」というのはつまりこういったっことにはDataStoreではなくMySqlなどをつかべきという話ですね？「GAEに外部キー...」ここでいうGAEというのはDataStoreと同義ですよね？「ReferencePropertyを利用すべきです。」自分の情報不足なのですが、自分はGoを使っています。そしてGoでは自分が調べた限りですとReferencePropertyという機能はありませんでした。しかし同じDataStoreを使っている以上、おそらくGoでも実装は原理的には可能だと考えています。そこでなのですが、ReferencePropertyは内部的にはどういった処理をされているかご存知ではないでしょうか？ご存知でしたら教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: @LoveExcel  GAEのデータベースと言えばDataStoreだから「GAEに外部キー...」は「GAEのDataStoreに外部キー...」の意味です。Goに詳しく知っていないですけど、多分静的形付けの制限があるから、Pythonの`PropertyReference`のような宣言が無理だと思います。英語SOの[この回答](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6192309/555515)によると、`*Key`を用いるべきです。

Comment: この方法でやってみます。ご回答ありがとうございました。